# How to use two column ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I want a 2-column `ScrollView`. In each column, there should be an `ImageButton`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_height="800dp"
android:background="#FFF"
android:layout_width="600dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/categoryLinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And the code:

```
        LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.categoryLinearLayout1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
        // ib.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cat1));

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.cat1);
        int width = 300;
        int height = 300;
        Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width,
                height, true);
        ib.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
        sv.addView(ib);
    }
```

But in this way, all 10 `ImageButtons` horizontally. What I need is, put 2 `ImageButton` in a row (it makes 600px) and go down, put more 2 `ImageButtons` etc. So there will be 5 rows for 10 `ImageButtons`.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you want them to scroll  independently then you'll need to use two ScrollViews

Comment: as per looking you requirement it looks grid view with 2 columns is also a good option ... http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: Yes, GridView seems to be the best option. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TableLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_height="800dp"
android:background="#FFF"
android:layout_width="600dp" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/categoryLinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Then in your code:

```
TableLayout sv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.categoryLinearLayout1);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
         ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(this);
         // ib.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cat1));
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
              R.drawable.cat1);
         int width = 300;
         int height = 300;
         Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width,
            height, true);
         ib.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
         ib.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(ib);
     }
     sv.add(tr); 
}
```